# asp.net and teams authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, microsoft-teams

Im developing a web app in asp.NET core MVC, which objective is to be deployed to microsoft teams. I need to use Azure AD authentication. Azure authentication cannot be used inside an iframe, but microsoft has an available work around (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad) to authenticate users in teams tab, which I was able to implement and retrieve the access token.

My questions are:

-How do I tell to the server that a user is logged in?

-If a user is in browser, is it possible to have both teams tab and browser authentication?

Very thankful for any (really any) help!

Answer (score 0):

- there is a [Microsoft Teams JavaScript client SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/msteams-client?view=msteams-client-js-latest), which will help you to log in and for server login you need to store user claims.
- MS teams tab authentication will work only under MS team apps, not in outside apps